# Twitter4j getRelatedResults() stopped working API v1.1

Tags: java, api, twitter, migration, twitter4j

Recently Twitter changed from API v1 to v1.1. I am using `twitter4j` to get replies and mentions related to the specified Tweet. The method that used to do such thing is called `getRelatedResults(id)`, but it no longer works.

I keep getting:

```
The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.
```

But I still haven't found an equivalent method in API v1.1.

Any suggestions?

What I have found:

The following code does not replace related results, put it is a good alternative to get replies:

You can use `InReplyToStatusId` field value using `Status.getInReplyToStatusId()`

Use the code code below recursively to get all replies or conversations of a tweet using API v1.1:

```
Status status = twitterAPI.showStatus(status.getInReplyToStatusId());
System.out.println(status.getText());
```

Comment: could you plz provide a sample code, how to use it?